# For TestCafe, is it possible to get a hook before the browser is launched?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Is it possible to get a hook on e.g. fixture before the browser is launched? The hooks on fixture (e.g. before) and test all happen after the browser is launched.

The only thing I can see to use is the [--app switch](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#-a-command---app-command) but I'm not sure that's enough for me. Any help appreciated.

m

Answer (score 2):

Could you please describe why you need this usage scenario?
Currently, there is no way to run the fixture hooks before the browser is launched. As a workaround, you can use the `createTestCafe function to run TestCafe tests from script. In this script, you can run any JS code you want before the tests start.
Please refer to the following article for details:
https://testcafe.io/documentation/402662/reference/testcafe-api/global/createtestcafe

Comment: I am using the electron plugin and need to perform some setup related to our electron app before it launches. I have used the --app switch to pass in a powershell script to run which seems to have solved my issue for now.